# Is it possible to have multiple GRANDPA Pause/Resume for one fork?

Tags: grandpa

While reading the spec `polkadot-host-spec_v0.1.1.pdf` is not clear if the host should track multiple or just one `GRANDPA Pause/Resume` consensus message per fork until the target block is finalized/imported. Another related question is, should we consider the `GRANDPA Pause/Resume` messages in the [`next change`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b75a253f148aa36fa17cf795b9f2fc2f22d0fcc5/client/finality-grandpa/src/authorities.rs#L268) rule where we return the [`effective_number`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b75a253f148aa36fa17cf795b9f2fc2f22d0fcc5/client/finality-grandpa/src/authorities.rs#L677) to never vote on chains with a number higher than the earliest handoff block number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GRANDPA Pause/Resume` have not been implemented in the substrate client code, therefore I would hold on implementing those for now.

We need to track multiple pending `Pause / Resume` signals per-fork, like we do for standard changes. Otherwise if finality is halted and there's a pending `Pause / Resume` signal, a further one being issued would make it impossible to import such a block and halt block production as well. We might be able to get away with just refusing to import a block that triggers a `Pause` while there is still a pending one, but e.g. if the pause is being triggered by an automated process (governance), then this could lead to the death loop explained earlier. It's also important to make sure we don't enact a `Resume` (on block depth) before the corresponding `Pause` been enacted (on finality). In that case `next_change` should also consider the earliest pending `Pause` when voting to finalize.

(Edited my original response significantly in light of your comment.)

Comment: According to the spec the `Pause` should be enacted on block finalization and `Resume` should be enacted on block import. As the `Pause` is enacted on block finalization should we consider it in the `next_change`?

Comment: Edited my response. I hadn't checked that the spec defined when to enact `Pause/Resume`. Enacting `Pause` messages on finality makes sense but it also makes the tracking considerably more complex. Also keep in mind that I haven't given that much thought to this yet since I don't have any plans of implementing this for now.